# Possible to get or resume loss and mAP graph for YOLO/darknet during training?

Tags: yolo, darknet

If I stop and resume training in the middle, the chart will only show the data from the iteration I am resuming from and onward. Is there a way to get the full loss chart or, when resuming, also plot the loss/mAP data before killing the training session? I need the chart for reporting/documenting purposes.